# Where are 'parameters map' in NoHandlerFoundException set?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, portlet

I'm trying to work out why below exception is thrown.

I think it is because a portlet was accessed in 'view' mode but for a reason I do not know the spring servlet container was unable to serve the request, is this correct ?

Where are the 'parameters map' in below exception set ?

> org.springframework.web.portlet.NoHandlerFoundException: No matching
>   handler method found for portlet request: mode 'view', phase
>   'ACTION_PHASE', parameters map[empty]

Here is the controller :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("VIEW")
public class DetailsController {
    @RequestMapping("VIEW")
    public String showDetails(final ModelMap modelMap, final RenderRequest renderRequest) {
        return "allDetails/details";
    }
}
```

Comment: showing your controller code (and maybe a part of the jsp) would help a lot

Comment: @Jerome Dalbert what jsp do you want to see, the one that redirects to "allDetails/details" ?

Comment: the JSP (or whatever) part that calls the controller

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are 3 ideas I can come up with (knowing how your controller is called would help). 
Try one of them, or a mix of them, and tell me if it worked.

**Idea 1 :** Remove `("VIEW")` for the showDetails @RequestMapping annotation.

```
...
public class DetailsController {

    @RequestMapping
    public String showDetails(final ModelMap modelMap, final RenderRequest renderRequest) {
        return "allDetails/details";
    }

}
```

This could work if your calling JSP has something like this : `<portlet:actionURL/>` : showDetails would be the default render method.

**Idea 2 :** Specify the action parameter for your @RequestMapping method annotation.

```
...
public class DetailsController {

    @RequestMapping(params = "action=viewDetails")
    public String showDetails(final ModelMap modelMap, final RenderRequest renderRequest) {
        ...
    }

}
```

This could work if your calling JSP has something like this :

```
<portlet:actionURL ... >
    <portlet:param name="action" value="viewDetails">
</portlet:actionURL>
```

**Idea 3 :** Add an empty method for the action phase.

```
...
public class DetailsController {

    @RequestMapping(params = "action=viewDetails")    // render phase
    public String showDetails(final ModelMap modelMap, final RenderRequest renderRequest) {
        ...
    }

    ...
    // Empty method
    @RequestMapping(params = "action=viewDetails")    // action phase
    public void actionMethod() {
    }

}
```

This could work if your calling JSP has something like this :

```
<portlet:actionURL ... >
    <portlet:param name="action" value="viewDetails">
</portlet:actionURL>
```

Comment: im not sure what is calling the controller. thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things to check here first:

1. Are there any parameters passed across to controller from jsp?
2. Is there a default Action method to handle empty param scenario?

Now if answer to first question is yes, then your jsp should have actionURL tag something like...

```
        <portlet:actionURL var="myAction">
           <portlet:param name="paramName" value="paramVal" />
        </portlet:actionURL>
        <form:form action="${myAction}"...
```

and its corresponding ActionMapping in Controller like...

```
        @ActionMapping(params = "paramName=paramVal" )
        public void myAction....
```

And if answer to second question is no, then define a default action method in the Controller like...

```
       @ActionMapping(param="!action") 
       public void defaultAction....
```

Hope this helps!